# How can I access the "_value" property of the object in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications, vuejs3

Trying to access the _value property of the object in Vue3. Does not allow obeject._value notation.

Here is the sample object in the state which contains the response data from the server

```
this is in store.state.skill:
tools:Array[267]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
8:Object


this is where it was copied using the computed object below
techstack:Object
 __v_isReadonly:true
 __v_isRef:true
 _dirty:false
 _setter:f ()
 _value:Array[267]
 effect:f reactiveEffect()
```

In my .vue file I used it like this:

```
 setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const tools = computed(() => store.state.skill.tools);
    .
    .
    .
    store.commit('stateName/mutation', { key: map(tools, 'id') });
```

The values that I get are always undefined when I try to map the id's from the 'tools' object. Is there a way to access the values which is the Array of objects found in 'techstack'?
I am trying to access the Array. What should my syntax be?

Comment: Have you tried `object.value`? How is this object created and set?

Comment: I tried accessing the array using object.value but it is undefined since there is no property named "value" inside the object. Apparently object._value is incorrect syntax.

Comment: The object is a computed value from the vuex state, whenever I try to access its values it returns the whole computed object itself. something like 

`const newObject = computed(() => vuexObject);`

Comment: If it's a Vuex store, then you'd do something like `newObject.state` to access its state, I'd think. Perhaps you could expand your code sample if not? You don't want to be reaching into `_value` directly.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry for not expounding it correctly.

It looked something like this `const newObject= computed(() => store.state.skill.anObjectInState);`

Comment: In setup `tools.value` in the `<template>` you need to loop like `<div v-for="tool in tools" :ikey="tool.id">{{ tool.name }}</div>`

Comment: @tony19, I am using lodash's function [lodash map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map). basically my final goal is to extract all the ids that is inside the array of objects from tools. in my vuex store there is an array of all the ids from the array of objects (i.e., `ids: [123, 456, 789]`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```js
map(tools, 'id')
    ^^^^^
```

`tools` is a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) returned from [`computed()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed). `lodash.map` expects a collection (an array), so giving it a `ref` would yield `undefined`.

#### Solution

To access the array stored in the `tools` `ref`, use its `value` property:

```js
map(tools.value, 'id')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-process-ref-value?file=src/App.vue)